# Create datetime object to use for comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create a date time object for **9:00 AM UTC** to use for comparison with the current utc time?

```
new_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 10, 24, 34, 198130)
```

I want to do it without the year, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Use strptime method

Comment: What's wrong with `new_date.hour`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the date part of it, use `datetime.time`:

```
import datetime

nine_am = datetime.time(9)

if datetime.datetime.utcnow().time() > nine_am:
    ...
```

Comment: nine_am = datetime.time(9) will be give me 9am on my system time correct? or is it 9am utc?

Comment: It's just an object representing "9am". Not local, not UTC; just a naïve "9am". In this example here I'm comparing that with the time portion of the current UTC datetime. You *can* make both `time` and `datetime.now` *aware*, but it's unnecessary for this operation.

Comment: this might sound weird but is it possible to do a == operation on datetime objects to start a function exactly at 9am?

Comment: For that you'd have to run the comparison at exactly 9am, which is likely the bigger problem. If you can run your code at exactly 9am to do the comparison… well, then you don't need to do the comparison.

Comment: i was thinking more of a script that runs 24/7 but executes certain functions at 9am

Comment: So it's constantly running in a loop constantly checking whether it's 9am? Sure, you can just do `==` instead of `>` as shown in the example, but this doesn't seem like the best approach. Scheduling certain actions through the system or such is usually more practical.

Comment: @user3702643: use `cron` or whatever your system's scheduler tool is.