# checking if two datetime objects are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime

time = datetime.time(21) 

while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    if datetime.datetime.now() == time:
        break
```

I am trying to set a specific time to run a function in my program. Unfortunately, the loop did not exit at 2100hrs as expected. Why is this so?

Comment: Is that how I told you to compare a `time` object?! https://stackoverflow.com/a/54590788/476

Comment: comparing `time` with `datetime`, is like check if `21:00:00` is equal to `2019-02-08 18:07:53.449365`. Obviously it wont break

Comment: The title of the question is not really accurate. You're asking how to compare two __hours not datetime objects__. Better edit it to get relevant answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to compare the hour:

```py
import datetime

time = datetime.time(21)
print(time)

while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    if datetime.datetime.now().hour == time.hour:
        break
```

That's if you really need to write this rather than using a built-in system scheduler like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: good answer. You could simplify it a little more as the **hour** attribute of a datetime object is just an int.  So no need to create the **time** variable.  if condition now becomes `if datetime.datetime.now().hour == 21 `

Comment: @ArranDuff You're correct. I was keeping the answer as close to the original as possible, and leave optimising up to the op.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime      

# set the datetime you want the loop to break out 
# datetime.datetime(year, month, date, hour, seconds)

set_dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8, 18, 19) 

while True:
   print("set date time:", set_dt)
   print(datetime.datetime.now())

   # check if the current date time is greater than the set_dt
   if datetime.datetime.now() > set_dt:
      break
print("out of loop")
```

OUTPUT:

```
.
. 
.
set date time: 2019-02-08 18:19:00
2019-02-08 18:18:59.999428
set date time: 2019-02-08 18:19:00
2019-02-08 18:18:59.999428
set date time: 2019-02-08 18:19:00
2019-02-08 18:18:59.999428
out of loop
```

EDIT:

If you only want the loop to break out when a certain hour:

```
if datetime.datetime.now().hour == set_dt.hour:
    break
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just compare dates,

```
yourdatetime.date() < datetime.today().date()
```

Or, obviously,

```
yourdatetime.date() == datetime.today().date()
```

If you want to check that they're the same date.

The documentation is usually helpful. It is also usually the first google result for python thing_i_have_a_question_about. Unless your question is about a function/module named "snake".

> Basically, the datetime module has three types for storing a point in time:

- date for year, month, day of month
- time for hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds, time zone info
- datetime combines date and time. It has the methods date() and time()
  to get the corresponding date and time objects, and there's a handy
  combine function to combine date and time into a datetime.